# How to avoid chunked encoding when the rest api is passing through APIMan?

Tags: apiman

I believe I got an error on my app.

When I try to retrieve info from url, I got an error on JSON object.
It occurs because some reason, the APIMan include a kind of encoding in the response. Here is my code:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("X-API-Key", xApiKey)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .get(ClientResponse.class);
String json = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

when I send a request through apiman, my response is showed with special characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String uri = "https://apiman.url/apiman-gateway/org/api/1.0/method";
    String apiKey = "894fd5b3-36f0-32974-xxxxxxxx"; 
    get("token", uri, apiKey);
}

// response is 1ff8\r\n{"data":...1ff8\r\nSim"[9867,"CAR\r\n1c7d\r\n...}\r\n0\r\n\r\n
```

when I do not use apiman, then my response is different as showed below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String uri = "https://192.168.56.22:8080/app/method";
    String apiKey = "not needed"; 
    get("token", uri, apiKey);
}

// response is ok {"data":...Sim"[9867,"CAR...}
```

**PS.:The part of '...' it was just me to not pass all data here.**

Does anyone had the same problem? It seems that some characteres has different encoding type.

**Edit.1:**

If I try to access the apiman url directly, the response is showed ok:

```
https://apiman.url/apiman-gateway/org/api/1.0/method?apikey=894fd5b3-36f0-32974-xxxxxxxx

// response is ok {"data":...Sim"[9867,"CAR...}
```

In another test, I used the cUrl method:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-API-Key:894fd5b3-36f0-32974-xxxxxxxx" 'https://apiman.url/apiman-gateway/org/api/1.0/method'

/* response is 1ff8
{"data":...
1ff8
Sim"[9867,"CAR
1c7d
...}
0

*/
```

**Edit.2:**

For some reason the problem occurs again.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: this post was modified because the question must be refactored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a custom policy plugin and override `doApply` method to remove the `Transfer-Encoding` header if it equals `chunked` using `ApiResponse` object.

```
apiresponse.getHeaders().remove("Transfer-Encoding");
```

And add the new custom policy plugin to your services. This is a simple [tutorial](https://vimeo.com/118262057) to create plugins

Comment: Solved! \o/ Thanks a lot @ulab.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best thing to do. This is occurs because my service is no passing the Content-Length on the Response Header. This is not a problem of APIMan. So I have to add the Content-Length on my backend server

Comment: you are right. Which server is it ? tomcat ? I think the problem is with the backend sever as we had similar issue with large files where content-length is not set.

Comment: I'm using JBoss Fuse with Apache Camel.

Comment: So, what I do was add the **HTTP Header Policy Plugin**, and then added "*Transfer-Encoding*" in the Strip Headers fields. So this is solved my issue.

Comment: I recently committed a small enhancement onto apiman's master to allow Content-Length to be passed through when no body-mutating policies are in the pipeline (i.e. doesn't change the payload in any way). It should be in the next release - but feel free to try it out and let us know how well it works for you.